# Subtract a value from each value in a column without any value going below 0

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I'm stuck on an issue in PowerQuery involving rounding monthly values but trying to keep the difference in the yearly totals less than 1.

I have data in this format:

| Year | Month | Value | Value Rounded | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | 0.3 | 0 | 0.3 |
| 2020 | 2 | 1.6 | 2 | -0.4 |
| 2020 | 3 | 3.5 | 4 | -0.5 |
| 2020 | 4 | 2.5 | 3 | -0.5 |

As above the yearly total would be 7.9 but with rounding it's 9.

What I want to do is take the total difference each year and use it to adjust the rounded values up or down so that the yearly difference rounds to 0.
I also want to ensure the the final rounded values don't drop below 0.

Using the example above the output data would look like this:

| Year | Month | Value | Value Rounded | Difference | Final Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | 1 | 0.3 | 0 | 0.3 | 0 |
| 2020 | 2 | 1.6 | 2 | -0.4 | 1 |
| 2020 | 3 | 3.5 | 4 | -0.5 | 4 |
| 2020 | 4 | 2.5 | 3 | -0.5 | 3 |

Now the difference between the yearly total and the final value total is only 0.1.

I figure I want to write a function that works out the total difference in the year and uses that as a counter to iterate against as it adjusts each row, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Also I realise that maybe a better approach would avoid this issue altogether!
Thanks!

Comment: First Question: So you want to round down each number, and round up each number, and then pick and choose among them to select the combination that has a sum closest to the original Value sum?  There would seem to be multiple answers, which brings us to second question: Please explain why a Final Value of [0/1/4/3] is a better solution then [0/2/3/3] or [0/2/4/2] each of which also has a final value total difference of 0.1

Comment: actually all of these are 0.1 off [0/2/3/3] [0/2/4/2] [1/1/3/3] [1/2/3/2] [1/1/4/2] [0/1/4/3]  why is any one of them preferred

Comment: hi horseyride, in this instance I've chosen to add the adjustment starting from the earliest date in the year as that best models what I'm looking at - but I agree other patterns could be considered just as valid.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are generating your `Value Rounded` column, but the algorithm you are using seems to be `round 1/2 away from zero`.

The **M** `Number.Round` function will round `1/2` to even which reduces the bias inherent in an algorithm that always rounds in the same direction.

Using that, the difference between the sums will only be 0.1.

If that is not good enough, there are other rounding algorithms that you could use.  The choice of a rounding algorithm will also depend on the distribution of values.  And that is something that cannot be determined by your example.  It is certainly possible to construct a set of values for which the differences are large (eg: 0.5 for all values using a round 1/2 to even algorithm), but that would probably be uncommon in real life.

For example:

***Original Table***
[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table9"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Month", Int64.Type}, {"Value", type number}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Rounded Values", each Number.Round([Value])),

//add totals row
    totals = Table.Combine({#"Added Custom",
     Table.FromRecords({
         [  Year="Totals", 
            Month=null, 
            Value = List.Sum(#"Added Custom"[Value]), 
            Rounded Values = List.Sum(#"Added Custom"[Rounded Values])]})})
     
in
    totals
```

***Result***
[image]

***Edit:** Here is code that does what you describe as well as round-to-even.  For certain values, your adjustment method seems to work better.  I have included both the Round to even and Adjust rounding columns in the results, and also added a Totals row, to make it easier for you to compare the results*

***Source***
[image]

***M Code***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table9"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Year", Int64.Type}, {"Month", Int64.Type}, {"Value", type number}}),

//round 1/2 to even
    roundToEven = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Rounded Values", each  Number.Round([Value])),

//Per your algorithm
    roundAdjust = let 
        nums = roundToEven[Rounded Values],
        adjustmentTotal = Number.Round(List.Sum(#"Changed Type"[Value]) - List.Sum(nums)),
        ns = Number.Sign(adjustmentTotal),
        adjust = List.Generate(
            ()=>[n=List.Max({0,nums{0}+Number.Sign(adjustmentTotal)}), adj=adjustmentTotal-Number.Sign(adjustmentTotal), idx=0],
            each [idx] < List.Count(nums),
            each [n=if [adj]=0 then nums{[idx]+1} else nums{[idx]+1}+Number.Sign(adjustmentTotal), 
                adj=if [adj]=0 then 0 else [adj]-Number.Sign(adjustmentTotal), idx=[idx]+1],
            each [n])
        in adjust,
//add as a column
    addCol = Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(roundToEven) & {roundAdjust},
        type table[Year=Int64.Type, Month=Int64.Type, Value=number, Rounded Values=Int64.Type, Round Adjusted=Int64.Type]
    ),

//add totals row
    totals = Table.Combine({addCol,
     Table.FromRecords({
         [  Year=null, 
            Month="TOTAL:", 
            Value = List.Sum(addCol[Value]), 
            Rounded Values = List.Sum(addCol[Rounded Values]),
            Round Adjusted = List.Sum(addCol[Round Adjusted])
            ]})})
in
    totals
```

***Results***
[image]

Comment: thanks for the response, I'm rounding use Number.Round([Value], 0) so it rounds to the nearest integer. The issue being I need integer values as it represents discrete events either happening or not happening.

I suppose another way of looking at it is I have a number of events I think will happen and a distribution for spreading them out, so I want to distribute that number of things in integer amounts that are as close to the distribution as possible.

Comment: @TadeosShahbazian There's something wrong with your example, then. `Number.Round(2.5,0) =>2` not `3` as you show. Possibly `2.5` is not really `2.5`. In any event, as I showed you in my example with code, the difference is only 0.1. Is that acceptable or not? I'd suggest using a defined rounding algorithm that works for your data.

Comment: @TadeosShahbazian See my latest ***Edit***.  I have tried to implement the algorithm you described, and included both in the results along with a totals column.  You can choose which works best with your real data, and edit out the undesirable algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

> "I want to do something with a number but I don't want the number to be negative."

There's a general approach for this kind of question:

```
=MAX(do_something(number), 0)
```

Like this, when the result of your operation yields a negative number, it will automatically be replaced by zero.